# Where do I get user and pass for email form api setup?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nodemailer, react-hook-form

I am trying to get this form working in Nextjs using 'React Hook Form'. So far I think everything is okay, but I need to know where to get the 'user' and 'pass' for the API to send the information in the form.

It is probably a stupid question but when learning how to get forms to work, all tutorials just explain how to console log the information to display it as an alert, which is not very helpful when trying to do it properly and get it working.

Hope someone can help me out, thanks

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer'

export default async (req, res) => {
  const {name, surname, companyName, email, numberOfEmployees, message, consentimiento } = req.body;
  const  transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.user,
      pass: process.env.pass
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using Gmail as your mailing service?

To get this working you'll probably need to set up an app password with your gmail account - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: Great help! And in regards to the user, would that be the email or the name I created to get the password? Thanks

Comment: The email - the name is I believe just for your reference.